# How to transfer the $id from my edit method to edit_validate method in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am doing a simple phonebook app to practice where I can add, show, edit, delete, and store it in my database. I am almost done doing it aside from 1 thing. I am having a hard time passing the edit method($id) parameter to a validation method. I tried to use

```
 $this->load->model("Phonebook");

    if ($this->input->server('REQUEST_METHOD') === 'POST') {
        // If the form is submitted, call the edit_validate method to handle validation and database update
        $this->edit_validate($myid);
```

to pass $myid to function edit_validate(). It only validated the form and when I successfully edited it, nothing changed in my db nor my main page where I posted the list of names from my db.
I am doing the best practices and was told validation should be separated.

Comment: *when I successfully edited it, nothing changed in my db nor my main page where I posted the list of names from my db* please post details/code of what you are trying to achieve and where you are failing...

Comment: It isn't clear what the problem is.  Are you saying you don't know how to get `$myid`?  Or that the `edit_validate()` method isn't working?  If `edit_validate()` isn't working, why show us these 3 lines of code and not `edit_validate()`?